# mongoose - How to create a nested subdocument of array of strings

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am doing a MERN app. For managing the photos of a product I am using multer to upload the files saving the paths relative to the files in a mongoose array of strings, so when i need to retrieve them i can use the paths. The problem is that when i want to store this array I get the following error:

```
ValidationError: images: Cast to Embedded failed for value "[ '0.jpeg', '1.jpeg', '2.jpeg', '3.jpeg', '4.jpeg', '5.jpeg' ]" (type Array) at path "images" because of "ObjectExpectedError"
```

the schema i am using in mongoose is based on general properties of a product with a subdocument that reference to the path where the images are:

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
    .
    .
    .

    images:imagesSchema,

    .
    .
    .
},{
    timestamps: true,
    usePushEach: true //Need to put this to work since $pushAll was deprecated since 2.4 
},  
);
```

and the imagesSchema is:

```
const imagesSchema = new Schema({
    // Array of strings
    images: [{
        type: String,
        required: false,
        default: ''
    }]
});
```

and the router that handles the post is:

```
const adminRouter = express.Router();

adminRouter.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

adminRouter.route('/products')
.options(cors.corsWithOptions, (req, res) => { res.sendStatus(200); })

.post(cors.corsWithOptions, authenticate.verifyUser, authenticate.verifyAdmin, upload.any("productImages"), (req, res, next) => {    
    

    //this is the array of images, the path is on the originalname
    const product_images = req.files.map(file => file.originalname)

    Cars.create({
        ...
        ...
        ...
        images: product_images,        
        ...
        ...
        ...
    })
    .then((product) => {
        console.log("Product Created ", product);
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(car);
    }, (err)=>next(err))
    .catch((err)=>next(err));
})
```

why am i getting this error regarding the error says the value I am trying to upload is an array and the schema expects an array?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The `images` field in `productSchema` is expecting to receive a value which is a document which can itself contain a field (also) called `images` (which would be an array of strings)